# Java:19: error New to Java

Tags: java

```
public class math1 {

  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    double a = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
    double b = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);

    double c = Math.sin(a);
    double d = Math.cos(b);
    double e = Math.pow(c, 2);
    double f = Math.pow(d, 2);
    double g = e+f;

    System.out.println("sin(" + a + ")^2 +" "sin(" + b + ")^2 =" + g);
  }
}
```

Above is my code and i keep getting this error:

```
javac math1.java
math1.java:19: error: ')' expected
System.out.print1n("sin(" + a + ")^2 +" "sin(" + b + ")^2 =" + g);
                                       ^
math1.java:19: error: not a statement
System.out.print1n("sin(" + a + ")^2 +" "sin(" + b + ")^2 =" + g);
                                                         ^
math1.java:19: error: ';' expected
System.out.print1n("sin(" + a + ")^2 +" "sin(" + b + ")^2 =" + g);
                                                            ^
3 errors
```

I am new to Java and was wondering what I am doing wrong, thanks!!

Comment: Make sure you are separating the hard-coded text and your variables by placing double quotes at the right places. That's your error.

Comment: error with your double quotes in system.out.println()

Answer (score 3):

You miss a "+" in the output line.

```
System.out.println("sin(" + a + ")^2 +"+"sin(" + b + ")^2 =" + g);
```

Answer (score 1):

remove +" from the code:

```
System.out.println("sin(" + a + ")^2 sin(" + b + ")^2 =" + g);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println("sin(" + a + ")^2 +"+" "+"sin(" + b + ")^2 =" + g);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your double quotes were a little off. I think you wanted

```
System.out.println("sin(" + a + ")^2 + sin(" + b + ")^2 = " + g);
```

But I suggest you use `printf` instead, like

```
System.out.printf("sin(%.2f)^2 + sin(%.2f)^2 = %.2f%n", a, b, g);
```

The [Format String Syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) is well documented and made for this kind of formatted output.

Answer (score 1):

System.out.println("sin(" + a + ")^2 +" "sin(" + b + ")^2 =" + g);

should be:

System.out.println("sin(" + a + ")^2 " + "sin(" + b + ")^2 =" + g);

What it does is concatenate all the strings to a single string and passes it to println.

Answer (score 0):

just omit your system.out and use this

```
System.out.println("sin(" + a + ")^2 sin(" + b + ")^2 =" + g);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
System.out.println("sin(" + a + ")^2 +sin(" + b + ")^2 =" + g);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the code to:

System.out.println("sin(" + a + ")^2 " + "sin(" + b + ")^2 =" + g);